# write in new file data with several strings from another file

Tags: python

what I did wrong

in file test.txt I have list ['some', 'another']

```
enter code here
import ast
with open ('C: \test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = str(f.readline())
    for im in ast.literal_eval(data):
        with open ('C:\new.txt', 'w') as file:
           print(im)
           file.write(im)
```

result: in file new.txt only one string:

```
some
```

but I need every strings in new line:

```
 some
 another
```

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the file with every iteration of the `for loop`.
Consequently, it is being closed and opened again. Open the file before the iteration:

```py
with open ('C:\new.txt', 'w') as file:
    for im in ast.literal_eval(data):
        print(im)
        file.write(im)
```

Comment: thanx!-)and 
file.writelines(im + '\n')

Comment: how to transform list data to string lines without module ast?